# Overriding the disco file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, discovery

I have an ASMX web service  and it is deployed behind a reverse proxy. I need to override the disco file by changing some of the links whichs are incorrectly created by the reverse proxy. Does this file get created on the fly? It there any way we can force a user to use the one we want them to use?

Comment: Check if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274984/wcf-webservice-behind-public-reverse-proxy