# WCF with SSL terminating load balance server

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, iis, ssl

we have 2 load balanced IIS servers which we want to host a WCF on. the entry URL is https but this is terminated at the load balanced server and changed to http before it gets to the IIS servers.

We are using .net 4, is there a built in configuration to handle this scenario?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem: you have a WCF service over HTTP that is then published to the internet as HTTPS and consumed by clients as HTTPS. Isn't the change handled transparently by your load balancer? Unless you want to e.g. use client certificates with the SSL and pass those back to the WCF servers won't it all just work? And presumably if your load-balancer handles this then it will have a solution for client certificates too. What issues are you seeing / worried about?

Comment: I wish it was that simple lol. the client does communicate with the load balancer over ssl however the load balancer then removes the SSL and sends data to the IIS servers using http. You can view the WSDL in a browser however the underlying URLs do not resolve to none-https addresses.

Comment: So the issue is just that the URL in the WSDL is wrong? I've had that with a JSP-based web service and we ended up creating a separate WSDL to publish and manually fixing the URL. I'd be surprised if you couldn't edit the endpoint URL in the published WSDL though within WCF.

Comment: Yeah, already tried a static wsdl with https however when it tries to resolve it on execution the IIS servers dont understand the https....

Comment: Here's [an old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261463/wcf-behind-load-balancer-how-to-setup/482995#482995) that suggests `[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]`

Answer (score 3):

`SSL` requires **point-to-point** connection. If you need a load balancer you probably need to use [Message Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx). The link I have provided discusses your options.